# Multi-module project in IntelliJ

Tags: java

Sorry about the question if it is stupid, but how actually i should build my multi-module project in Java, so I can have two runnable applications inside it?
For example I have three modules:
1.Models(Entities)
2.App(SpringBoot Application using #1) - runnable
3.Tests App(SpringBoot App with some Postman endpoints for testing the #2 with using #1) - runnable

Actually I am trying to build everything to be maven-dockerized, but i got stuck :/
especially with the POM files.
I've created a empty maven project and started inserting the other ones.
I succeeded to run the test application with a controller, but when I try to run the #2 app it starts and stops with code 0.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's tricky to answer without more details, e.g. we can't know why your program immediately returns an exit code without seeing your program or your build configuration, or what commands you're running and what you expect to happen. Maven offers capabilities to create multi-module projects (nesting maven projects inside maven projects), is this what you're using? How are you trying to run the test application and the #2 app?

Comment: They are SprintBoot applications and automatically generate a runnable class.
With the application.properties i am setting the connection to docker DB and RabbitMQ.

Comment: I'll be thankful if you tell me about this nesting of the projects, which I actually made to some point, but i am not pretty sure how to proceed at this moment.

Comment: I wish I could offer more help, but I'm not familiar with spring boot, docker or RabbitMQ. I'm still not entirely sure what your end goal is, but best of luck. Multi-module maven projects usually consist of a "parent" project and multiple "submodules" (e.g. 1 for your test app, 1 for your other app) https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module but this is just a matter of how you choose to structure your project. I'm not sure how helpful it is for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an empty module and add your common maven libraries for all modules into that pom.xml file and after that create modules on that. if you want to add specific libraries for the sub module you can add them into the sub module. if you have any doubts please refer to this.
https://youtu.be/yVzi3wuTUE4